# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: - Fastai, Although that file exists

Tags: python, flask, deep-learning, web-deployment, fast-ai

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 34, in <module>
    learn = setup_model_pth(PATH_TO_MODELS_DIR, NAME_OF_FILE, classes)
  File "app.py", line 31, in setup_model_pth
    learn.load(learner_name_to_load, device=torch.device('cpu'))
  File "C:\Users\Caden\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 269, in load
    state = torch.load(source, map_location=device)
  File "C:\Users\Caden\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 584, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "C:\Users\Caden\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 234, in _open_file_like
    return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode) 
  File "C:\Users\Caden\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 215, in __init__
    super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models\\model_best.pth'
```

I had cloned one github repository and while running it shows this error.
The main problem is its showing No such file or directory: 'models\model_best.pth' but actually there is a directory models/model_best.pth , so why its coming like models\model_best.pth and not like .models/models_bestpth'.

source code:
'''

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import sys
import os
import glob
import re
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import requests

# Import fast.ai Library
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *

# Flask utils
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from PIL import Image as PILImage

# Define a flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

NAME_OF_FILE = 'model_best' # Name of your exported file
PATH_TO_MODELS_DIR = Path('') # by default just use /models in root dir
classes = ['Actinic keratoses', 'Basal cell carcinoma', 'Benign keratosis',
           'Dermatofibroma', 'Melanocytic nevi', 'Melanoma', 'Vascular lesions']

def setup_model_pth(path_to_pth_file, learner_name_to_load, classes):
    data = ImageDataBunch.single_from_classes(
        path_to_pth_file, classes, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224).normalize(imagenet_stats)
    learn = cnn_learner(data, models.densenet169, model_dir='models')
    learn.load(learner_name_to_load, device=torch.device('cpu'))
    return learn

learn = setup_model_pth(PATH_TO_MODELS_DIR, NAME_OF_FILE, classes)

def encode(img):
    img = (image2np(img.data) * 255).astype('uint8')
    pil_img = PILImage.fromarray(img)
    buff = BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
    return base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

def model_predict(img):
    img = open_image(BytesIO(img))
    pred_class,pred_idx,outputs = learn.predict(img)
    formatted_outputs = ["{:.1f}%".format(value) for value in [x * 100 for x in torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs, dim=0)]]
    pred_probs = sorted(
            zip(learn.data.classes, map(str, formatted_outputs)),
            key=lambda p: p[1],
            reverse=True
        )

    img_data = encode(img)
    result = {"class":pred_class, "probs":pred_probs, "image":img_data}
    return render_template('result.html', result=result)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', "POST"])
def index():
    # Main page
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        img = request.files['file'].read()
        if img != None:
        # Make prediction
            preds = model_predict(img)
            return preds
    return 'OK'

@app.route("/classify-url", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def classify_url():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.form["url"]
        if url != None:
            response = requests.get(url)
            preds = model_predict(response.content)
            return preds
    return 'OK'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = os.environ.get('PORT', 8008)

    if "prepare" not in sys.argv:
        app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

'''

Comment: give the full path for your model.pth

Answer (score 0):

Your code is searching for the file in the root directory of the computer, which is not where your file is. It's there in some folder, and that's why the file couldn't be found.

Change path variable from

```
PATH_TO_MODELS_DIR = Path('')
```

to

```
PATH_TO_MODELS_DIR = Path('.')
```

It'll search for your folder models and file model_best.pth in current working directory.